# Nomenclature of simple molecules

Tags: nomenclature

I'm from Slovakia, 16, and I'm really confused about the English simple molecule (oxides, hydroxides, salts, acids) nomenclature. I guess we do it differently. To sum it up: we have suffixes from 1-8 to communicate the oxidation number of an element in a molecule. We put those suffixes at the end of the elements stem, combine it with the word for what kind of molecule it's forming (oxide, hydroxide, ...), and then we can determine from that name and the oxidation number of the other elements (if it's an oxide then oxygen if it's a hydroxide then the hydroxide anion and so on) what it's chemical formula is. Is it done the same way in English speaking countries? Do you just have to search for the oxidation number in a periodic table? If not then how?

Thanks!

Edit: we use these suffixes for oxidation numbers:

1. -ný/á
2. -natý/á
3. -itý/á
4. -ičitý/á
5. -ičný/ečný/á
6. -ový/á
7. -istý/á
8. -íčelý/á

(ý or á is based on gender of the word...)

They all represent the positive oxidation number of a part of a simple molecule, for example, Al2O3 would be "oxid hlin-ITÝ" because aluminum is hliník in Slovak and -itý means that the oxidation number of the aluminum is +3. 
How would you write down $\ce{Al2O3}$ in English? And also how do you name salts, bases, and acids?

EDIT2(for Karsten Theis)

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{Formula} &  \text{English name} & \text{Slovak name}  &\text{Oxidation #}  \\
\hline
\ce{FeCl2 }& \text{ferrous chloride, iron(II) chloride} &  \text{chlorid želez-natý}  & +2\\
\hline
\ce{FeCl3 }& \text{ferric chloride, iron (III) chloride} & \text{chlorid želez-itý} & +3\\
\hline
\ce{FeO }& \text{iron(II) oxide} &  \text{oxid želez-natý}  & +2\\
\hline
\ce{Fe2O3 }& \text{iron (III) oxide} & \text{oxid želez-itý} & +3\\
\hline
\ce{N2O}& \text{nitrous oxide} & \text{oxid dus-ný} &+1 \\
\hline
\ce{NO}& \text{nitric oxide} & \text{oxid dus-natý} &+2\\
\hline
\ce{HNO2}& \text{nitrous acid} & \text{kyselina dus-itá} &+3\\
\hline
\ce{HNO3}& \text{nitric acid} & \text{kyselina dus-ičná} &+5\\
\hline
\ce{NO2-}& \text{nitrite} & \text{dus-ita-n} &+3\\
\hline
\ce{NO3-}& \text{nitrate} & \text{dus-ičita-n} &+5\\
\hline
\ce{N^3-}& \text{nitride} & \text{nitrid} &-3\\
\hline
\ce{CrO}& \text{chromous oxide} & \text{oxid chróm-natý} &+2\\
\hline
\ce{CrO3}& \text{chromic oxide, chromium trioxide} & \text{oxid chróm-ový} &+6\\
\hline
\ce{Cr2O3}& \text{chromium (III) oxide} & \text{oxid chróm-itý} &+3\\
\hline
\ce{H2CrO4}& \text{chromic acid} & \text{kyselina chróm-ová} &+6\\
\hline
\ce{HCl}& \text{hydrochloric acid} & \text{kyselina chlóro-vodíková *} &-1\\
\hline
\ce{HClO}& \text{hypochlorous acid} & \text{kyselina chlór-na} &+1\\
\hline
\ce{HClO2}& \text{chlorous acid} & \text{kyselina chlor-itá} &+3\\
\hline
\ce{HClO3}& \text{chloric acid} & \text{kyselina chlor-ečná} &+5\\
\hline
\ce{HClO4}& \text{perchloric acid} & \text{kyselina chlor-istá} &+7\\
\hline
\ce{Al2O3}& \text{aluminum oxide} & \text{oxid hlin-itý} &+3\\
\hline
\ce{CaO}& \text{calcium oxide} & \text{oxid vápen-natý} &+2\\
\hline
\ce{Li2O}& \text{lithium oxide} & \text{oxid lít-ný} &+1\\
\hline
\end{array}

*(vodíková means that that acid only has hydrogen and not oxygen)

Comment: Can you show a few examples? My experience has been that I can understand "chemistry" in any romanic/germanic language without any problem.

Comment: Generally there are two types of simple (inorganic) names: Element-(oxidation number)-oxide/chloride (e.g. Cu-(II)-oxide, CuO), and less systematic names like carbondioxide.

Comment: There seems to be no better way than to practise chemical nomenclature like a language with rules (like grammar) and vocabulary; which equally depend a bit from the natural language, too.  From a search about oxides (https://glosbe.com/en/sk/oxide) interestingly Slovak -- in comparison to English, Lithuanian, German -- seems to regularly invert the order of "elements of meaning" (metal; oxide / sulfate) in a pattern like the romanic French, Spanish; and equally slavic Polish and Russian.  Just substitute "sk" by lt, ge, fr, sp, pl, ru.

Comment: Pavol, thanks for adding that table - it nicely illustrates how systematic the naming is. @Curt F. - thanks for the edits, I fixed them here too. I hope it is correct now, but if someone can check the Slovak language ones...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, French and German, the names are less systematic. Here are some examples from English:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\text{Formula} &  \text{Name} & \text{Oxidation #}  \\
\hline
\ce{FeCl2 }& \text{ferrous chloride, iron(II) chloride} &  +2\\
\hline
\ce{FeCl3 }& \text{ferric chloride, iron (III) chloride} &  +3\\
\hline
\ce{N2O}& \text{nitrous oxide} &  +1 \\
\hline
\ce{NO}& \text{nitric oxide} &  +2\\
\hline
\ce{HNO2}& \text{nitrous acid} &  +3\\
\hline
\ce{HNO3}& \text{nitric acid} &  +5\\
\hline
\ce{NO2-}& \text{nitrite} &  +3\\
\hline
\ce{NO3-}& \text{nitrate} &  +5\\
\hline
\ce{N^3-}& \text{nitride} &  -3\\
\hline
\ce{CrO}& \text{chromous oxide} &  +2\\
\hline
\ce{CrO3}& \text{chromic oxide, chromium trioxide} &  +6\\
\hline
\ce{Cr2O3}& \text{chromium (III) oxide} &  +3\\
\hline
\ce{H2CrO4}& \text{chromic acid} &  +6\\
\hline
\ce{HCl}& \text{hydrochloric acid} &  -1\\
\hline
\ce{HClO}& \text{hypochlorous acid} &  +1\\
\hline
\ce{HClO2}& \text{chlorous acid} &  +3\\
\hline
\ce{HClO3}& \text{chloric acid} &  +5\\
\hline
\ce{HClO4}& \text{perchloric acid} &  +7\\
\hline
\ce{Al2O3}& \text{aluminum oxide} &  +3\\
\hline
\ce{CaO}& \text{calcium oxide} &  +2\\
\hline
\ce{Li2O}& \text{lithium oxide} &  +1\\
\hline
\end{array}

I think this is what happens if names of substances were chosen before the concept of oxidation state (and electrons etc) existed. It would be nice to have something more systematic, but that would mess up all the older literature.

It would be fascinating (to me, at least) to see the Slovak names in another column of this table. Also, I am glad that chemical formulae exist that are universal in any language.

Comment: I'll try later today to make that table for you. And give you some insight in naming the acids and salts because thats the hardest.

Comment: @PavolKomlos Have a look at http://www.rsc.org/suppdata/c9/dt/c9dt00352e/c9dt00352e5.pdf (freely available supplementary informtion of https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2019/DT/C9DT00352E#!divAbstract) as a handy English guide.

Comment: English is certainly less systematic, but there is method to the madness.  "-ic" was assigned to the highest known oxidation state, then "-ous", then "hypo-_-ous" for lower known oxidation states. I think "per-_-ic" for an even higher state came later, but I'm not sure. The big difference from Slovak is that the English refers to relative oxidation states rather than absolute, ie -ic is always more oxidized than -ous, but it might be +5 or +3 or +2 depending on the element.

Comment: @Andrew - Great comment! Some method ... but often the oxidation state is different by two for "-ic" and "-ous". Sometimes they are correlated from acid to oxide, and sometimes not (nitrogen compounds). Sometimes, a compound with an oxidation state between "-ic" and "-ous" gets discovered after naming compounds (see chromium). It is a nice historical record, but pretty tough on learners (pre-internet, I guess).